# How can I open a new browser tab from within JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

How do I write a JavaScript function that opens a new browser tab at a specified URL?
I know how to do this in In HTML using a link with target="_blank", but in my case I need to do it from within the JS function.

Thanks

Comment: opening new browser tab is browser specific behaviour. in FF, you can configure whether to open new tab or not when using `target="_blank"`, in new browsers (IE7+, chrome, e.g.) they open in new tab. however old browsers open in new window.

Comment: Like it has been said, it is pretty much browser specific

Answer (score 0):

You cannot specify to open in a 'new tab', but if you have a tabbed browser this behavior is configurable. For example, I believe Firefox has this behavior by default

See Tools -> Options -> Tabs -> check "open new windows in a new tab instead"

The following JavaScript will work a charm for you

```
<script>
    window.open("http://www.google.com", "google"); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Javascript has no built-in support for tabs, because not all Javascript capable browser have tabs at all (think IE6). You can at most open a new window (though that might get pop-up blocked of course).

Some browsers might show those new windows as tabs. I believe Opera does this.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
  window.open("http://stackoverflow.com/", "SO");
</script>
```

More info is [here](http://www.javascript-coder.com/window-popup/javascript-window-open.phtml).

Comment: That will open the page in the current window, not a new window or a new tab.

Comment: No. Excerpt from w3schools.com: The open() method is used to open a new browser window.

Comment: Just one time, the window will be named SO so the next time a window is open to "SO", the second link will be launch in the first window.

Comment: Thanks, Rodrigo, didn't take this into account. But it is possible to drop second parameter, though.