# Make a link open in another tab with javascript

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I open a new browser tab from within JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1547836/how-can-i-open-a-new-browser-tab-from-within-javascript)

Is there any way to make a link open in a another window without using target=blank, ?  I am pulling in feeds in my site, and I want those feed links to open in another tab.  Is there a javascript function that can do this.

Comment: -1 For no research effort. Related links to your right has the answer to your question.

Comment: Technically this cannot be controlled, since it is hooked to the users browsers settings. Some browsers don't even have tabs function and if they have, its impossible that they work on the same principals.

Answer (score 0):

Use: 
`window.open('page.html','_newtab');`

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
        <script>   
    function load() {

             var load =     window.open('http://www.domain.com','','scrollbars=no,menubar=no,height=600,width=800,resizable=yes,toolbar=no,location=no,status=no');

                    }
       </script>
```