# Is it possible to detect and avoid the user opening a new tab in an online test project?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I am doing an online test project in PHP.  Once the user logs-in, he can take up the test. I want to know that, is it possible to make the user not to open a new tab or any other tab other than the test portal, using jquery or javascript. And also if the user attempts to open a new tab , he should be warned..

Comment: You're asking if the PHP can do it?

Comment: No i am asking, whether you can detect and block the user opening any other tab using javascript or jquery..

Comment: I missed the comma `other than the test portal, using jquery`

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Even if you succeed, the user can always open a second browser...

Comment: If you don't want them to find solution on stackoverflow, cut the internet connection :) seriously, it completely against the browser policy and totally horrible as UI experience.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1547836/how-can-i-open-a-new-browser-tab-from-within-javascript

Comment: ya i want my application to be secure enough, so that no one can copy the answers by opening another tab or any other click outside the current webpage .

Comment: Note that jQuery can't do anything that JavaScript can't do because jQuery is just a JS library. Regarding your actual goal, if somebody wants to cheat they're going to cheat unless you actually physically supervise them in a controlled testing lab. They may use another browser, or even another computer (or smart phone).

Answer (score 1):

No, that is against browser security policies.
What if the user opens another browser instead of tab ? How do you handle that ?

What if he has two computers , or a smartphone to use during the test ?
There is no sureshot way to make your online test safe from cheating attempts.

Comment: actually my aim is to restrict the user not to copy the answers from the internet. is ter any other way to do that???

Comment: If you are a programmer, you could make a c# or java program that will load a specific page, acting like a browser but not configurable by the user. With official browser, I don't think you will find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you write some sort of a Plugin on Firefox (I believe even Chrome extensions doesn't allow you to do this), you cannot do this on a normal browser using javascript. It would be a security issue if you could.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is not possible, JavaScript runs in the window context, opening new windows/tabs is up to the browser, the JS running in your page is unaware of those actions.